# How do I remove quotes from a boolean value in a JSON string?

Tags: java, json, string

I have:

```
String example = {"test":"true"}
```

but I want to have:

```
example = {"test":true}
```

How can I convert the first string to the second?

Comment: `if myString.startWith("String ") { return myString.substring(7); }` ???

Comment: please post your code (**edit** the original post, don't add it in the comments, don't add it as an answer)

Comment: what is the context ? What are you trying to achieve ? Do you use a specific library or framework ?

Comment: If "test" is supposed to be a boolean value, whatever is building that JSON string should be building it without the quotes. Where does the JSON string come from? Are you building it yourself?

Comment: I've updated your question title pretty significantly. Your original title didn't really match up with what you were asking. **Please let me know if I changed it incorrectly**, and I'll revert it (or we can work together to clarify it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [regular expression](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/) and/or String class method like 'replaceAll'.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `String result = example.replaceAll(":\"true\"", ":true"};` and `String result = example.replaceAll(":\"false\"", ":false"};` if there are only boolean values.

Comment: This is dangerous if only a subset of the json is being shown, and there are other values which are not neccessarily boolean but could have the value true or false.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it done right, then you need to make sure to take care of other conditions in the json data.
Assuming parse_data is JSONObject (java)

```
String raw_tag = parse_data.toString();
        raw_tag = raw_tag.replaceAll(":\"true\"", ":true");
        raw_tag = raw_tag.replaceAll(",\"true\"", ",true");
        raw_tag = raw_tag.replaceAll("\\[\"true\"", "\\[true");
        raw_tag = raw_tag.replaceAll(":\"false\"", ":false");
        raw_tag = raw_tag.replaceAll(",\"false\"", ",false");
        raw_tag = raw_tag.replaceAll("\\[\"false\"", "\\[false");
System.out.print(parseData);
```

Comment: this is especially useful when you are serializing data to a model or datastore(*NOSQL)